Troubleshooting Proxy Issues on Android Studio Emulator
I have set up an emulator using Android Studio and attempted to configure a proxy as shown in the attached screenshot. Unfortunately, once the proxy is set up, none of the apps or browsers on the emulator are able to connect to the internet. The emulator works perfectly fine without the proxy settings, so I believe the issue lies with the proxy configuration.
To ensure the proxy is functioning correctly, I tested it with Proxifier, and it worked without any issues. Given that the proxy is operational and the emulator works without it, there seems to be a problem specifically with how the proxy is set up in the emulator.
Could you please provide detailed steps or troubleshooting tips to help me get the proxy working on the Android Studio emulator? Any guidance or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.
enter image description here
After setup emulator from setting, I input the paid proxy credentials in the field.
